# django-cms plugin edit css background image 'placeholder_attr' is not a valid tag library error

Tags: python, django, django-cms

i have istalled djangocms-css-background 1.0.3, run migrations
and included `djangocms-css-background` in `settings.py`

in my template, i have the code below.

```
{% load placeholder_attr %}

<div style="{% placeholder_attr 'My Background Css Placeholder' 'CssBackground' 'css_background' %}">
  {% placeholder 'My Background Css Placeholder' %}
</div>
```

Everytime i run the server, i encounter rhe error `'placeholder_attr' is not a valid tag library: Template library placeholder_attr not found`

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

djangocms-css-background depends on djangocms-placeholder-attr which has been [deprecated](https://github.com/WnP/djangocms-placeholder-attr)
Use [cmsplugin-css-background](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmsplugin-css-background/0.1.0) instead.

1. Add the DOM element you'll be using:

   ```html
       <div id="hero"></div>
   ```
2. Add the background image placeholder. **css_selector** should point to the DOM element you're targeting.

```
    {% with css_selector='#hero' %}
        {% placeholder 'element_background_image' %}
    {% endwith %}
```

3. Limit the plugins of **element_background_image** placeholder to **CssBackgroundPlugin**

```
    CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
        'element_background_image': {
            'plugins': ['CssBackgroundPlugin'],
            'limits': {
                'global': 1,
            },
        },
    }
```

The **FilerCssBackgroundPlugin** is enabled if **filer** is installed. 
The plugin will print out the applicable **background-image** css in the placeholder

Comment: I struggled with this because it took be a while to realise I need to add the element as a class to one of my tags.  A bit slow on my part but the note might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Your `load` statement should look:

```
{% load placeholder_tags placeholder_attr %}
```

Then do `pip install djangocms-placeholder-attr` and put `'djangocms-placeholder-attr'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: This gets me a new error 'placeholder_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library placeholder_tags not found @Moses Koledoye

Comment: By added to `settings.py` you mean `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes , i added it to installed apps in settings.py filr

Comment: i have done the pip install djangocms-placeholder-attr , and put  'djangocms-placeholder-attr' in INSTALLED_APPS , then python manage.py migrate and then restarted my server. the error 'placeholder_tags' is not a valid tag library still appears

Comment: You should `makemigrations` before `migrate`. In case that does not work also, try removing the `placeholder_tags` and see what happens with only `placeholder_attr`

Comment: No changes detected for makemigrations

Comment: After removing placeholder_tags, my old error 'placeholder_attr' is not a valid tag library returns

Comment: You can have have a look at the docs in case there is something you're missing: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangocms-css-background/1.0.3